# How to add additional page to be printed in Visual C++ 6

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I have a picture that is getting printed in my MFC application. I'd like to add another page with another picture, so that 2 pages will be printed.
I know this is very poor description but the application is so big I can hardly know what's where.

Answer (score 2):

First, locate your view-class. This will usually be something like `CMyAppView` - where MyApp is the project name. Inside this view class all printing stuff is handled.

You will most likely find overrides for `OnPrint` and `OnFilePrint`. In this methods you can adjust printer settings and page layout. And they will internally call `OnDraw` for your view. So, in OnPrint you add another page with `EndPage` and `StartPage`, and in OnDraw you really decide what you print.

If your printout should be different to your view on screen, you may have to store additional information on what to print when inside your class.

Answer (score 0):

The `EndPage` and `StartPage` functions in the `CDC` class might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Posibly you need to locate the print function and what data is printed.